# How to upload file into a directmessage via slash command?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I managed to use my bot to respond a message publicly in a directmessage channel via slash command.

But what I couldn't get it to work is using [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) in a slashcommand in a directmessage.

my channel id: `DQW7XA9FC`, the prefix `D` denotes a directmessage

error that I get:

```js
{
  code: 'slack_webapi_platform_error',
  data: {
    ok: false,
    error: 'channel_not_found',
    response_metadata: {
      scopes: [
        'channels:history',
        'chat:write',
        'groups:history',
        'im:history',
        'incoming-webhook',
        'mpim:history',
        'reactions:write',
        'workflow.steps:execute',
        'files:write',
        'app_mentions:read',
        'commands'
      ],
      acceptedScopes: [ 'files:write' ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any helps would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the API page states :

> By default all **newly-uploaded files are private** and only visible to
> the owner. They **become public** once they are **shared into a public
> channel** (which can happen at upload time via the channels argument).

Can this be the reason for the error ?